# Comparing String from Dictionary to Multiple Strings

Tags: python

I'm receiving a dictionary from a server and have a few expected values to get back, however there are times that I get values I don't want to process my code for. Is there a way I can do this check without needing to repeat `dict["travel"] !=`

```
if dict["travel"] != "Bee" and dict["travel"] != "Fly" and dict["travel"] != "Bird":
    print("Didn't receive flying animal of choice")
    return
```

Ideally my code would look like...

```
if dict["travel"] != ("Bee" or "Fly" or "Bird")
    print("Didn't receive flying animal of choice")
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if either A, B, or C is in X, you do:

```py
if X in [A, B, C]
```

In your case this is:

```py
if not dict['travel'] in ['Bee', 'Fly', 'Bird']
```

To check the opposite, remove the `not` keyword

```py
if dict['travel'] in ['Bee', 'Fly', 'Bird']
```

Answer (score -1):

checks if dict["travel"] is not present in the list ["Bee", "Fly", "Bird"].
You can try this code:

```
if dict["travel"] not in ["Bee", "Fly", "Bird"]:
    print("Didn't receive flying animal of choice")
    return
```